# When using Apache Beam locally, how to utilize persistant caching for queries in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, beam, google-bigquery-storage-api

For development purposes, I'd like to cache the results of queries in BigQuery made by `beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery` connector - so I'd be able to load them quickly from the local file system when running the exact same query in the next times.

The problem is that I cannot run any PTransform before `beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery` to validate existence of caching and skip the reading from BigQuery as a result.

Currently I came up with two possible solutions:

1. Creating a customized `beam.DoFn` for reading from BigQuery. It will include the caching mechanism, but might underperform comparing to the existing connector. One variation might be inheritance of the existing connector - but it will require knowledge of Beam "under the hood" - which might be overwhelming.
2. Implementing the caching when building the pipeline, and the resulting step will be determined according the existence or inexistence of the cache (`apache_beam.io.textio.ReadAllFromText` or `beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery`, respectively).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that preceding `beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery` by any other PTransform is impossible by design. Unfortunately it's currently not well reflected in the Python SDK docs - but according to Apache Beam's [official Java documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/PTransform.html): "A root PTransform conceptually has no input" - and as the equivalent java PTransform [BigQueryIO.Read()](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Read.html) inherits from `PBegin`, it puts the seal on preceding it with something else.

However, I found a workaround which resembles the second approach that I suggested in the question - implementing a `beam.PTransform` (not `beam.DoFn`) that dynamically returns the appropriate PTransform when building the pipeline, according to the existence or inexistence of cache. It looks like this:

```py
class ReadFromBigQueryWithCache(beam.PTransform):

    def __init__(self, query):
        super().__init__()
        self.query = query

    def expand(self, input_or_inputs: InputT) -> OutputT:

    ## Implement here logic for caching
    ## if cached:
    ##  return input_or_inputs | beam.io.ReadFromAvro(file_pattern="path/to/cached_results")
    ## else:    

        return input_or_inputs | beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
            query=self.query
        )
```